# Schedule Change

Tags: communication, management, new-job, email

I interviewed with a company under the premise that my schedule would be Monday-Friday 9am-5pm. However, they sent out official schedules yesterday and my schedule was set as Tuesday-Saturday 2pm-11pm which doesn't work for me because I take care of my special needs grandfather while my mother works. How should I go about emailing my manager about this? 
Sidenote: I've started training with the company 12/3 and they just send out schedules 12/6.

Answer (score 8):

> However, they sent out official schedules yesterday and my schedule
>   was set as Tuesday-Saturday 2pm-11pm which doesn't work for me because
>   I take care of my special needs grandfather while my mother works. How
>   should I go about emailing my manager about this?

Don't email - use the telephone.

Explain that you expected your schedule to be Monday-Friday 9am-5pm, based on what you heard during your interviews.

Explain that this is important to you, since you take care of your special needs grandfather in the evening.

Then listen.

It may be that they just made a mistake in the schedule (the most likely answer). It may be that you misunderstood during the interview process. It may be that the late schedule is only temporary. Who knows.

Be prepared with a response if the schedule they gave you is what they now expect you to work, for whatever reason. If your grandfather's care isn't flexible, then you may need to find a new job.

Comment: It also might be that this is the training schedule. I have known organizations where they train people at specific times or with specific experienced workers to be able to control the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the original schedule in writing or at least your interviewers name.

**Refer to that schedule when you tell them what you just told us.**

Most likely it was just one arm not knowing what the other does or that it got lost during shift planning.
Could also be a way for them to test the waters to find out how important your schedule is to you.